# Expand last value of string column to groupby Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
+--------+----+
|id      |name|
+--------+----+
|       1|    |
|       1|    |
|       1|    |
|       1|Carl|
|       2|    |
|       2|    |
|       2|John|
+--------+----+
```

What I want to achieve is to expand the last value of each group to the rest of the group:

```
+--------+----+
|id      |name|
+--------+----+
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       2|John|
|       2|John|
|       2|John|
+--------+----+
```

It looks pretty easy but I am struggling to achieve it because of the columns' type.

What I've tried so far is:

`df['name'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].transform('last')`

This works for int or float columns, but not for string columns.

I am getting the following error:

`No numeric types to aggregate`

Thanks in advance.

## Edit

bfill() is not valid because I can have the following:

```
+--------+----+
|id      |name|
+--------+----+
|       1|    |
|       1|    |
|       1|    |
|       1|Carl|
|       2|    |
|       2|    |
|       2|    |
|       3|    |
|       3|    |
|       3|John|
+--------+----+
```

In this case, I want id = 2 to remain as NaN, and it would end up as John, which is incorrect. The desired output would be:

```
+--------+----+
|id      |name|
+--------+----+
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       1|Carl|
|       2|    |
|       2|    |
|       2|    |
|       3|John|
|       3|John|
|       3|John|
+--------+----+
```

Comment: The answer given is correct. You just need to group ie `df.groupby('id').bfill()`

Comment: You're totally right, thanks so much !!! Indeed, to get it to work, you should do: ```df.groupby('id')['name'].bfill()```

Answer (score 2):

If the empty values are NaN, could you try fillna

```
df['name'] = df['name'].bfill()
```

If not, replace empty strings by NaN.

Comment: That is not valid in my case, but fits my question tho. I will edit it !

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dff = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   "name":["","","","car1","","","","","","john"]})
dff = dff.replace(r'', np.NaN)
def c(x):
   if sum(pd.isnull(x)) != np.size(x):
       l = [v for v in x if type(v) == str]
       return [l[0]]*np.size(x)
   else:
       return [""]*np.size(x)


df=dff.groupby('id')["name"].apply(lambda x:c(list(x)))
df = df.to_frame().reset_index()
df = df.set_index('id').name.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'name'})
```

output

```
   id  name
0   1  car1
1   1  car1
2   1  car1
3   1  car1
0   2      
1   2      
2   2      
0   3  john
1   3  john
2   3  john
```